# qwtplot - adding data

Tags: qt, qwt

```
QVector<double> x(101), y(101);
for (int i=0; i<101; ++i)
{
     x[i] = i/50.0 - 1;
     y[i] = x[i]*x[i];
}

QwtPlotCurve *curve;
curve->setData(x,y);
curve->attach(plot_all[0]);
```

Assuming `plot_all[0]` is my QwtPlot, what wrong here? It crashes my program, made in linux.

Comment: Your `curve` is not initialized at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not allocating `*curve` so it does not point to a valid object.  Try replacing `QwtPlotCurve *curve` with

```
QwtPlotCurve *curve = new QwtPlotCurve();
```